# Amazon ec2 ubuntu 18.04 sudo apt-get not working

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

I have configured amazon ec2 instance in Asia pacific (Mumbai) region. I can able to login to the server using ssh. When I am trying to run "sudo apt-get update" command, it throwing the connection timed out error.

Error message,

```
root@ip-172-31-4-13:/home/ubuntu# sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::11). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::17). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.162), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.31), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.24), connection timed out
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::11). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::17). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::11). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::17). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::17). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::11). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.23), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.162), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.31), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.24), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.26), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done
```

Screenshot below,

[image]

In the same region, another server is working fine. I am tried to create new server sevaral time (in this region alone) facing the same issue. Other region servers are working fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not post images of screenshots.  Edit your question to include the actual text.  You can use the preformatted { } option

Comment: Check your security group permits outbound traffic and your instance's IPv6 configuration is correct for your VPC.

Comment: You've done something wrong with your connectivity. Because it's showing IPv6 addresses you need to double check your OS and VPC including all firewalls are correctly configured. Can you ping those servers from your instance, IP4 or 6? Can you ping other websites, like 1.1.1.1? You might be able to force apt-get to use IPv4.

Comment: I have checked outbound traffic and made all traffic open.

Comment: Try telnet archive.ubuntu.com 80 and see that the server can connect to the ubuntu package site.